# "Not that fast a car" "Not that good an idea"

Tags: adjectives, comparative-constructions

> 1. This is not that fast a car
> 2. Not that good an idea

Can someone confirm that this is correct? Or do I need an *of*?

Sentences like those don't make much sense in my native language. if I were to translate it from my native to English, it'd be something like *not so good a car*. Of course, trying to find the correlation between one's native language and English isn't always helpful, but I just have trouble understanding this construction although I use it a lot.

Comment: Looks good and is idiomatic. "Not so good..." is also fine. Not much more to add, really.

Comment: Alright good to hear. Is this something people use a lot? Also what exactly is the difference between this and the version without that? ( "This isnt a fast car") Is "This isnt that fast a car" the negative version of "such"? Or essentially "Not so fast a car" if this is even correct I dont know. Ok you said so is possible now what do people use more often? So or that?

Comment: "Not that" is used much less than "not so" but it is still readily understood. "This is not that fast a car" means that it's not slow, but it is possibly not as fast as one might like (or expect). "Not so..." has the same meaning.

Comment: Ok I have to aks one more thing. When you say "Not so" do you mean "Not so fast a car" or "This car isnt so fast" ?

Comment: You _will_ hear colloquially in U.S. regional dialects: _This is not that fast **of** a car_ and _Not that good **of** an idea._ This is informal and colloquial and accepted, but never used in formal (or even most informal) writing.

Comment: Either. Maybe an expert will enlighten us. I can only give you the usage.

Answer (score 1):

> Not that fast a car.
>
> Not that good an idea.

Both the sentencs are idiomatic and correct grammatically.

Some people also use *of* after an adjective in such a construction. For example, *not that fast of a car*,  *not that good of an idea*.  The usage of *of* sounds superfluous; so the sentences without *of* are better and more common.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+good+of+an+idea%2C+that+good+an+idea&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20good%20of%20an%20idea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20good%20an%20idea%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Adding "of" to those sentences sounds in my ears as bad as "would of" instead of "would have"

Comment: @mplungjan, I agree with you.